# Dictionary with two keys and one value without hashing

Tags: c#, dictionary, key

I'm looking for a better way to do the following.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

Dictionary<int, string> namebyID = new Dictionary<int, string>();
Dictionary<string, int> idbyName = new Dictionary<string, int>();
Dictionary<string, string> valuebyName = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // users favorite dessert

/* Lets store information about "leethaxor" */
namebyID.Add(1234, "leethaxor");
idbyName.Add("leethaxor", 1234);
valuebyName.Add("leethaxor", "cake");

/* use case 1, I'm given an ID and i need the user's favorite dessert*/
if (namebyID.ContainsKey(1234))
{
    string username;
    namebyID.TryGetValue(1234, out username);
    if (valuebyName.ContainsKey(username))
    {
        string dessert;
        valuebyName.TryGetValue(username, out dessert);
        Console.Write("ID 1234 has a username of " + username + " and loves " + dessert + "\n");
    }
}

/* use case 2, I'm given a username and need to make sure they have a valid ID*/
if (idbyName.ContainsKey("leethaxor"))
{
    int id;
    idbyName.TryGetValue("leethaxor", out id);
    Console.Write("username leethaxor has a valid ID of " + id + "\n");
}
```

I'd really like to not use 3 different dictionaries, as the `id`, `username`, and `value` are all related to one another. Hashing `key1(id)` and `key2(username)` together won't work because I'm only given one or the other, not both.

Comment: Then you shoulr create a class that holds all these related information.

Comment: Please explain what is the "this" in "better way to do this". Makes it much easier to help

Comment: Is this the same question you posted earlier? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369716/c-sharp-dictionary-with-two-keys-and-value

Comment: @DavidG Seems to be the same context, but obviously OP already used the solution from what was suggested to him/her within that question. So That´s not a duplicate at all.

Comment: Why use both ContainsKey and TryGetValue?

Answer (score 2):

You should definitly use your own class that holds all those information that belongs together. Relying on different dictionaries is a mess and gets really complex and complicated the more information you´r putting into those dictionaries.

So in your case you may create a class, let´s call it `Person`. Every `Person` has an `Id`, a `UserName` and a `Value`:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now create a list of those persons, e.g.:

```
var list = new List<Person> { 
    new Person { Id = 1234, UserName = "leethaxor", Value = "Cake" },
    new Person { Id = 2, UserName = "Berta", Value = "AnotherValue" }
};
```

Now you can get the `person` with a given `Id` or a given `UserName`:

```
var aPerson = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id = 1234);
```

or

```
var aPerson = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName = "leethaxor");
```

You should definitly have a look on the basics of object-oriented programming, which is about objects and their behaviour.

Comment: Do note that looking up user by ID or Name using LINQ usually performs slower than using the key of a Dictionary. But it is unclear whether performance is a concern for the OP.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Fair point. However OP can still add the instances into a dictionary. Creating a class has nothing to do with this, only with how those instances are retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a class? Also, use TryGetValue() instead of ContainsKey(). [What is more efficient: Dictionary TryGetValue or ContainsKey+Item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382681/what-is-more-efficient-dictionary-trygetvalue-or-containskeyitem)

```
public class User 
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public string Value;
}

Dictionary<int, User> userById = new Dictionary<int, User>();
```